# Dell XPS l502x: multi card reader

Tags: 13.10

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on my Dell XPS l502x.

```
kernel: 3.11.0-15-generic
arch: x86_64
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug, so I'm trying to get a solution by asking here.

If I don't boot my laptop with an SD card inserted, the SD-card-reader won't be
detected.

I have to run

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

as root every time I want to use the card reader. This problem is present since Ubuntu 11.10.

Any ideas for a workaround on this?
Maybe an init-script?

If you need more information, just let me know.

By the way: booting an older kernel doesn't help.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a Solution. It was a Kernel Bug listed [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40802)

Whatever caused this Bug was fixed as of Kernel Version 3.12.
I just installed the V3.13 Kernel from the [Ubuntu Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13-trusty/)

The cardreader works fine now :-)